# Imagens se duplicando na hora da transferência com Ajax jQuery!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom, primeiramente me desculpe se eu estiver sendo inconveniente na pergunta, é a minha primeira.
Eu tenho um uma função em jQquery e Ajax que fazem upload de fotos e tem uma pagina PHP para fazer a validação:
Esse é o HTML:

```
<form method="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" onclick="Uploadfile('upload','upload_com_previsualicao_funcao.php')">
        <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" onchange="Preview(this,'imagem')">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
```

E aqui é o JavaScript:

```
function Uploadfile(form,caminho){
    form = '#'+form;
    console.log(form);
    // console.log(caminho);

$(''+form+'').submit(function(){//ao clicar no submit
    $.ajax({
        url: ''+caminho+'',
        method: "post",
        data: new FormData($(''+form+'')[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').fadeIn("fast");//faz aparecer rapidamente
        },
        success: function(retorno){
            alert("enviada");
            $('#loading').fadeOut(3000);//faz desaparecer
            // alert(retorno);
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            alert( "Não foi possivel enviar a resposta. Tente denovo mais tarde!" );
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        });
    return false;
});
}
```

E aqui o PHP:

```
<?php
if (!$_FILES["imagem"]["error"]>0)
{
$n = rand (0, 10000000);
$extensao = pathinfo($_FILES["imagem"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$img = $n."resposta_atividade.".$extensao;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], "paratodos/".$img);

echo "<pre>";
echo "<br>";
echo "$img";
echo "<br>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "<br>";
echo "</pre>";
echo "a";
}
?>
```

Ele chega a fazer o upload normalmente mas por motivos que desconheço ele duplica a imagem, creio que o erro esteja no Ajax e não no PHP.

Não sei se fui bem claro, mais basicamente é assim ele faz upload certinho mais acaba duplicando a imagem.

E essas aspas que eu estou concatenando no jQuery, eu utilizei porque não estava identificando as variáveis como URL, id e tals.

Comment: Qual o código da função Preview?

Comment: Olá  Marabesi, o evento Preview é um que estou utilizando para fazer um pre-visualização do upload, achei desnecessário postar o código aqui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não coloque o *event handler* `.submit` dentro da função e nem utilize `onclick` no form para chamar uma função. Quando você clica em qualquer parte da área do form irá chamar a função e criar um novo *event handler*, e quando clicar no botão para submeter o formulário, irá chamar a função 2 vezes, por isso está duplicando a imagem, porque está fazendo na realidade 2 envios.

Não precisa de função extra, basta usar apenas a função do `.submit`. Nela você consegue pegar todos os dados do form que disparou o evento.

Coloque a URL no action que o JavaScript irá pegar e colocar no Ajax:

```
<form method="" action="upload_com_previsualicao_funcao.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
   <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" onchange="Preview(this,'imagem')">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

E no Ajax você pega a URL com `this.action` e o próprio formulário com `$(this)`:

```
$('form').submit(function(){//ao clicar no submit
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        method: "post",
        data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').fadeIn("fast");//faz aparecer rapidamente
        },
        success: function(retorno){
            alert("enviada");
            $('#loading').fadeOut(3000);//faz desaparecer
            // alert(retorno);
        },
        error: function( data ) {
            alert( "Não foi possivel enviar a resposta. Tente denovo mais tarde!" );
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Olá Sam, muito obg, era isso mesmo, eu ainda estou começando com js, ejquery, e queria fazer uma função de upload para qualquer formulário de upload. Bom mais muito obg e eu vou dar umas estudadas em eventos mais aprofundadamente. E novamente desculpe a pergunta um pouco besta! Até mais campeão